# What code is keeping this grey box here?

Tags: php, html, css

On my website I am trying to remove this large grey box at the top of my site over the menu by making it transparent. I can remove the grey but then it is white, and I cannot for the life of me figure out where that is coming from. I want to make it transparent but I can't find what needs to be changed in order to do this.

[Here](https://theunlighted.com/index.php/account/profile/khailz) is my site

Because of the framwork I use it seems

```
body {
  font-family: Lato;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  color: #de5900;
  background-color: #3b3939;
}
```

in the bootstrap.css file are blocked by modules in the T3 framework which can be moved from the template manager

Comment: ask clearly. I don't think people will understand which grey box. ;)

Comment: You're right sorry, fixed :)

Comment: Post the relevant code here. This question will be useless to others when your website changes.

Comment: I don't know the code I'm changing which is why I was asking. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is the gray box on the header, the gray color seems to be coming from the `background-color` property defined in `bootstrap.css` line 271. Which itself is weird as you seem to have edited the core bootstrap file (I don't remember bootstrap having a gray background) and that is not good practice. You should always add your custom CSS to your own css file such as `styles.css` and override the Bootstrap CSS so that in future you can upgrade the bootstrap files without affecting your custom code.

Anyway commenting out the `background-color` property and adding `float:left` property to `#xg_masthead > img` seems to get you closer to your goal.

Comment: Than you very much, I haven't edited the bootstrap file but it's probably because of the T3 framework it's using. Thank you for this tip

Comment: In that case, you can create your own custom CSS file and add something like this to override the background color: `html > body{ background-color: none; }`